# XPATH: p element who's immediate preceding sibling is a p

Tags: html, xpath

I am trying to select the first p element who's direct preceding sibling is also a p element. I have highlighted the below code with example of what i am looking for please.

```
<div class="vacancy-left">
    <h2>Machine Operator / Print Operator</h2>
    <h3>Vacancy Ref:</h3>
    <p>I-1056</p>   
    <p>Are you self-motivated with a..</p> <!-- THIS NODE -->           
    <p>The ideal candid...</p>
    <p>Hours of Work Monday- Friday 07.30-16.30</p>             
    <h3>Salary:</h3>
    <p>Start pay from £8.00 per hour</p>
    <p> Immediate Start</p>
    <h2><a href="../../contact.php">Apply For This Vacancy</a></h2>
    <p></p>
    <p><a href="../industrial.htm">Return to Industrial Vacancies</a></p>
</div>
```

I've tried a couple things such as .//p[preceding-sibling::p] but that selects a few p elements that have any preceding element as a p.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `//p[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::p]]` to select all `p` elements where the nearest preceding sibling element is also a `p` element, however it would select more than one `p` in your sample as several `p` elements have another `p` element as the nearest preceding sibling element.